# Site behind a reverse proxy - subfolder

Tags: 8, uri, proxies

We are using a public apache web server as a reverse proxy for to show a drupal instance (to the client). The website should come up in http://publicSite/path
The Reverse proxy contains basic apache configuration pointing a "subfolder" to the internal webserver. Something like:

```
ProxyPass /path http://internaldomain/
ProxyPassReverse /path http://internaldomain/
```

The problem is that Drupal 8 has no longer a $base_url and the site is broke (CSS, JS). Adding publicSite in the $settings['file_public_base_url'] does not help. CSS/JS and links to themes are still broken.

There is a settings section on a Reverse Proxy in the settings.php, but it does not address the issue on accessing the website from a /subfolder url. 
Any hints to solve this issue!?

Comment: Related: https://medium.com/@lmakarov/drupal-8-and-reverse-proxies-the-base-url-drama-c5553cbc9a3e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to reverse proxy all the asset directories like here (this proxies site preosasde via real site proreos):

```
ServerName preosasde

ProxyPass /themes/ http://proreos/themes/
ProxyPassReverse /themes/ http://proreos/themes/

ProxyPass /core/ http://proreos/core/
ProxyPassReverse /core/ http://proreos/core/

ProxyPass /vendor/ http://proreos/vendor/
ProxyPassReverse /vendor/ http://proreos/vendor/

ProxyPass /sites/ http://proreos/sites/
ProxyPassReverse /sites/ http://proreos/sites/

ProxyPass / http://proreos/asde/
ProxyPassReverse / http://proreos/asde/
```

Take care about the order of that entries and be aware that you will loose your users credentials (cause of the different domain).

Comment: Thank you for the solutions. Seems logic.
I am trying to connect through a *subfolder* path.
So drupal is installed at root of *proreos*, but the access should come from preosasde/drupal.
I tried changin correcting the ProxyPass & ProxyPassReverse and although this is fine, drupal aims link resources to absolute paths. So if I am at http://preosasde/drupal the link to 'sites' will be /sites, aiming to find it at root...

Comment: Leaving them on, with the expense of having additional proxy-spaces blocked helps, but again, this is a problem once the website is configured to have clean-urls. URLs are linked now to absolute paths. It feels the use of a $base_url was neccessary in Drupal, pitty that functionality is removed

Comment: Bad problem, yes. I can do it with mod_rewrite because I have not too much paths to relink. 10 years ago, I would have re-programmed mod_proxy to rewrite the URLs :-) ... maybe there's an option for this? Don't know, sorry.

Comment: Appreciate your feedback :)